# Debugging is not Working

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

When i play the game its working fine but when i debug the script.Break point goes to the next execution statement and when i press the jump button on unity then session not goes to the debugger and its not working.But when i stop the debugging on `MonoDevelop` game works fine.


[image]

[image]

Code

```
public class player : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool onGround;

    private float chargedJump;

    private float maxJump;

    void Start () {

        onGround = true;

        chargedJump = 0f;

        maxJump = 10f;

    }
    void Update () {
        if(onGround){

                     if(Input.GetButton("Jump")){

                if(chargedJump<maxJump){
                    chargedJump +=Time.deltaTime*10f;
                }
                else{
                    chargedJump = maxJump;
                }

            }
            }
```

Comment: Fundamentally what you are doing here is debugging *Unity*, not debugging your game code. When you are at a breakpoint in code in Monodevelop, the Unity editor is not responding to your input! If you want to debug what happens when you press Jump, try putting your breakpoint on your line `47` instead.

Comment: @DanPuzey line `47` respond the input but why it does not respond if i break point to line `44` because i want to check if it's true or not.

Comment: Line 47 is a breakpoint that will *only be hit* when your condition is true, and (critically) *after* the condition is evaluated. Line 44 is a breakpoint that is hit every frame, *before* the condition is evaluated. It stops Unity from running, and so you can't click Unity and press your key at that point to influence the flow of the code. This is, I'm afraid, a fundamental of debugging: you can't interact with a process at a breakpoint except through the debugger.

Comment: That is to say: you code *is* responding when you breakpoint at line 44, but breakpointing at line 44 (every frame) leaves you no useful way to press a key for your debugged code to detect.

Comment: @DanPuzey Wonder if your extended explanation is worth adapting into an answer? Could be helpful to future Unity scripters that are trying to work with breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Converting my comments to an answer, per suggestion...)*

Fundamentally what you are doing here is debugging all of Unity, not just your game code. There's a big difference: when you are at a breakpoint in MonoDevelop, the Unity editor is not responding to your input! If you want to debug what happens when you press Jump, try putting your breakpoint on your line 47 instead.

Line 47 is a breakpoint that will only be hit when your condition is true, and (critically) after the condition is evaluated. Line 44 is a breakpoint that is hit every frame, before the condition is evaluated. It stops Unity from running, and so you can't click into Unity and press your key at that point to influence the flow of the code. This is, I'm afraid, a fundamental of debugging: you can't interact with a process at a breakpoint except through the debugger.

That is to say: your code *is* responding when you breakpoint at line 44, but breakpointing at line 44 (every frame) leaves you no useful way to press a key for your debugged code to detect, as you can't switch to Unity and press a key before the next breakpoint is hit.

(As a side note that I'd not encourage: what *might* work is if you wrap a delay around your code that stop it from being called/hitting the breakpoint for a second or two. You could hold down the key in Unity *until* the breakpoint is hit, at which point the input system would hopefully have recognised the keypress. This state would still be in effect as you stepped through the code. However, this is a horrible thing to try to do, so I'd not recommend it.

What you *could* try if you want to prove the value is put a conditional breakpoint that is only hit when the key is pressed...)

Comment: i upload a new image which is image 3 i want to debug that script.I break point the method but when i start debugging it does not step in step out i don't know what to do

Comment: reply that comments please

Comment: You can't change a question so drastically once you've asked it (especially when it's already been answered!). Post a new question.